# Scripts Dinamicos

Tags: c#, script

Porque al ejecutar mi sistema, y tener un js donde necesito hacer un debuggeo, se abre un archivo dinamico del mismo, juntos con otros mas, que no se de donde salieron o porque, pero cuando detengo el sistema desaparecen, como le puedo hacer para que no me abra esos scripts dinamicos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Con esto puedes corregir]

Intenta corregirlo con esto, o de lo contrario intenta desactivarlo desde aqui:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE) (Visual Studio 2017 and 2019)